# Slick slider active slider color change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Am working with slick slider, here i am trying to achieve highlight the current slider image and need to fadeout the remaining slider images

Expecated result is

[image]

Created fiddle is [Fiddle link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bEBPRX)

i had added following css to get my result

```
.slick-current.slick-active.slick-center {
    opacity:1;

}
.slick-slide  {
    opacity:0.5;
    background: #000;
    border-left:3px solid #fff;
    border-right:3px solid #fff;
}
```

Opacity is working but right and left images are white overlayed instead of black,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `opacity` has been set on the same element as the `background` colour, so the colour's being "diluted" as the `.slick-slide` gets made translucent.

The quickest way I can think to change it would be to add a rule like:

```
.carousel {
  background-color: #000
}
```

and remove the `background` from `.slick-slide`. This way the opacity will fade the image and the black background will be unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe css filter can solve your problem. How about that?

```
.slick-current.slick-active.slick-center {
    opacity:1;
  filter: brightness(1) !important;
}
.slick-slide  {
    opacity:1;
    background: #000;
  filter: brightness(.1);
    border-left:3px solid #fff;
    border-right:3px solid #fff;
}
```